# Активация venv не подменяющая имя python

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, venv

Виртуальное окружение уже создано. Вроде делал всё как всегда:

`. ../venv3.6/bin/activate`

(`source ../venv3.6/bin/activate` тоже пробовал)

Далее появляется:

```
(venv3.6) [user@fedora dir]$
```

Но

```
(venv3.6) [user@fedora dir]$ python --version
Python 3.10.0
```

Содержимое *../venv/lib/* :

```
[user@fedora dir]$ ls ../venv3.6/lib/
python3.6
```

```
[user@fedora dir]$ ls ../venv3.6/bin/ | grep python
python
python3
python3.6
```

`which python`, `which python3`  и `which python3.6` даже после активации venv ведут к системным версиям python. Самих версий python3 в системе (Linux Fedora) стоит довольно много, недавно устанавливалась ещё одна.

```
[user@fedora dir]$ ls -l ../venv3.6/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 9 ноя 13 11:21 ../venv3.6/bin/python -> python3.6
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, куда ведут команды python — `which python` / `which python3` / `which python3.6`

Comment: В папке `../venv3.6/bin/` есть какой-нибудь python?

Comment: И какая у вас операционная система? Возможно, вы когда-то обновили системный python и тем самым случайно сломали venv?

Comment: @andreymal, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: `ls -l ../venv3.6/bin/python ` куда ведет?

Comment: @eri, дополнил вопрос, вашим замечанием.